# Can't sign in to Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I can't sign in to Django admin with any of the superusers I've created. Tried creating new superusers, changing passwords, etc. - no error messages for any of these processes, but still can't sign in.

I'm not sure if it's related, but I also can't run django-admin.py commands. Here is what I've done so far:

```
$ django-admin.py validate  
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.  
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings  
$ django-admin.py validate  
Error: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named mysite.settings
```

sys.path shows ['/Users/joerobinson/Sites/django/mysite' ... (other stuff on path)]

Is there something else I need to do to register the mysite module?

python manage.py runserver works fine.

**Conclusion**
For the question about logging in to django admin, I did not have django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend included in my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS - adding this allowed me to sign in to admin.

I'm still working on the django-admin.py configuration question (which appears to not be related), and will reopen it in a separate question.

Comment: users must be staff members to login to admin. set is_staff = True for those user.

Comment: is_staff was set appropriately... same problem.

Comment: `django-admin.py` is not for running project-specific commands like `validate`. Use `manage.py` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Am I correct in thinking DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE issue may be related to my inability to sign in to admin? Even after reseting passwords, creating new superusers, etc., I can't sign in. I can access the users in the shell and see that they're appropriately provisioned with privs, etc., but they don't seem to connect for admin.

Comment: Thanks for adding Conclusion part. It did the trick !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to answer one of your questions, the parent folder of `mysite` is what needs to be on the python path. Adding `mysite` itself to your python path will expose the contents of `mysite`, not the `mysite` module to python.

As for runserver working / passwords not working, I haven't a clue. Have you customized anything with authentication?

Can you start the shell and try authenticating with your superuser?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate

You said in a comment that "is_staff was set appropriately... same problem." -- does that mean you were able to log in with the first superuser to set `is_staff`??

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the link, Yuji. I have some very strange behavior, indeed: I can't authenticate the user in the shell (authenticate() returns None). If I retrieve the admin user via the api (admin_user = User.objects.get(username='joe')), I can check the password with admin_user.check_password('mypwd') and see that I have the password correct. Any idea why authenticate() wouldn't work if check_password() does? Thanks for uncovering a little more of this mystery.

Comment: That's utterly insane! What is your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS set to? The default `ModelBackend` in `django.contrib.auth.backends` does exactly what you did: `user.check_password('pwd')`. You know, I might put in some debugging code temporarily in django's authenticate function to see what it's doing as it's going through your auth backends.

Comment: You sir, have just made my day. I just *knew* this was a foolish oversite on my part - did not have the default in place. Thank you, thank you!!

Comment: Excellent call, Yuji - just had an issue myself where I couldn't log into Admin after installing django-socialregistration.  Didn't realize I was overriding an existing default when I added my own AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS to settings.py and had to include that default in there.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had "SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True" because I was trying SSL configurations. Just commenting this line worked.

Comment: WOW this bug ("feature") is so crippling if you are testing production configurations. That did it. Thanks for the solution. Took me hours to figure out why I couldn't log into the admin.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similair problem but, I couldn't login on the admin interface even after removing the database and creating it from scratch. The problem was caused by a real silly mistake.

Don't run `python manage.py testserver` by accident. Make sure you use `python manage.py runserver`.